# Page break CSS not working in lightning LWC Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, css3

I am trying to do page break in LWC. But it is not working. Below is the code . How to do page break in lightning while printing the page to pdf.

```
<template>
    <div>
      <lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout-item>
          First Page
        </<lightning-layout-item>
      </<lightning-layout>
    </div>
    <div style="page-break-before: always;">
      <lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout-item>
          Second Page
        </<lightning-layout-item>
      </<lightning-layout>
    </div>
           <lightning-button label="Print" title="print" onclick={printpreview} class="printbutton"></lightning-button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <lightning-button label="Back" title="Back to record" onclick={back} class="back"></lightning-button>
        </template>
```

Comment: I tried your code and can see it work: https://imgur.com/a/J4nVxUe

Comment: Please try it in LWC..not in normal HTML compiler..

Comment: I literally created a LWC component and embedded in aura app and took screenshot

Comment: ok then... i am not sure why it is not working for me..

Comment: Have you added that compoent in a page or appbuilder?

Comment: the LWC is in appBuilder..On Appbuilder i have a button. On click of the button, i am navigating to child LWC and in child LWC there is print button.

Comment: Can u please try putting a lightning-layout and lightning-layout-item inside the <div> and see if it is working

Comment: Have you solved it? I have the same issue

Comment: yes it is solved. Wrap the componet with Aura app, then page break css will work